# Migrate Azure AD users to On-Premise Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, active-directory

Basically we have an on premises application which uses on-premise active directory and we have another web application, which uses Azure AD for authentication. The users of both the application are same.

We want to onboard the user only at one place (Azure AD) and not twice.

Is there a way to sync/send users from Azure AD to on-premise active directory ? (We will add the user in Azure AD and the same user will get added to on-premise AD automatically)

I found articles mentioning the steps to sync users from on-premise AD to Azure AD, but could not find much on how to sync users from Azure AD to on-premise active directory.

Answer (score 0):

> But could not find much on how to sync users from Azure AD to on-premise active directory.

There is no way to sync **Azure AD** users to **On-Prem AD** , as process of **Azure AD Connect** works only **On-Prem** to **Azure AD** , but you can sync **Azure AD** user passwords back to **On-Prem AD** using below methods.

**Password writeback** and **device writeback** are two features in **Azure Active Directory** that enable the synchronization of passwords and devices between **Azure AD** and **on-premises Active Directory**.

**Password writeback** : It allows users to reset their passwords in Azure AD and have the new password synchronized back to their on-premises active directory and also helps to ensure that users have a consistent password across both Azure AD and on-prem AD.

**Device writeback** : It allows devices that are registered in Azure AD to be synchronized back to the on-premises AD environment. With device writeback, the device information in Azure AD is synchronized back to the on-premises AD environment.

Refer the [Microsoft Document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/azure-ad-sync-to-on-premise-ad/m-p/1472915) created by **PeterRising**

[Azure AD Connect: When you have an existing tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-existing-tenant#hard-match-vs-soft-match)